# How to improve memory usage in Python while processing an array of billions of entries?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, apple-m1

I'm building a script which processes an array with billions of entries. For each element of this array, I need to sum each element with all the elements in the array. For example:

```
list = [0, 1, 2]
result = [0+0, 0+1, 0+2, 1+0, 1+1, 1+2, 2+0, 2+1, 2+2]
output -> [0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4]
```

I'm using `numpy.ogrid()`  to create this array of billions of entries (I think it's faster). Also, I'm trying to use `itertools.product()` to get the products of it and be able to sum them.
This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
import itertools

startTime = datetime.now()
array = np.ogrid[150000000:3000000000]
print("Array creation took: ", datetime.now() - startTime)

for element in (list(itertools.product(array, array))):
    if(element[0]+ element[1] == 3756499519):
        print("Found: ", element[0])
        print("Found: ", element[1])
        break

print("Running took: ", datetime.now() - startTime)
```

Everything looks great when this array is small. But when I try to run it with the current size, `zsh` is killing the process, probably because of lack of memory `zsh: killed     /usr/bin/python3`. Is there any way to improve the memory usage? I don't know, maybe remove the elements after being processed?
I'm using Macbook Air M1.

Comment: `(list(itertools.product(array, array))):` the `list` part negates any benefit you get from using the iterator

Comment: You are using the wrong algorithm if your code is representative of what you are trying to do,  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-an-array-a-and-a-number-x-check-for-pair-in-a-with-sum-as-x/

Comment: Note also that with n values, you will have n^2 products, which makes this O(n^2). Sorting first would allow you to do that in  O(n x log(n)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list(itertools.product(...))` is killing you. Itertools is lazy, which means it doesn't create a data structure that isn't currently being used. List breaks that, by forcing the iterator into list format. Removing the call to `list()` will enable you to use an iterator instead, which will be much more memory efficient.

Something like this will use the itertools package efficiently:

```
for a, b in itertools.product(array, array):
    if(a + b == 3756499519):
        print("Found: ", a)
        print("Found: ", b)
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use broadcasting:

```
import numpy as np

# Minimal example:
x = np.array([0, 1, 2])
# Get the result
r = (x+x[:,None]).flatten()
# r = array([0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4])
```

But if you only need to find a pair of value that sum to a specific number, and that those number are included in a subset of Z (the integer set) then you can just solve the equation:

```
x+y = desired_sum
y >= min(subset(Z))
```